# Replace certain values in a filepath string to make the filepath more dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have written a VBA code to update an excel dashboard to present "weekly KPI figures".
The data used to populate/refresh the dashboard comes from another excel file that I download weekly, at the moment I change the filepath manually every week when I run the macro, I wish to make it more "dynamic".

An example of the filepath: C:\Users\John\Downloads[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE **100122**.xlsx

*** Do note for every new weekly file, only the date changes to every Saturday of the week e.g. **100822** thereafter **101522** in **MMDDYY** format.

For every KPI value that populates/refreshes the dashboard it comes from a cell value from that weekly file, for example: "='C:\Users\John\Downloads[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!**R12C68**"

*** Do note every week the cell number (column) increases by 1, e.g R12**C69** thereafter R12**C70**, it ends at R12C81 for the last saturday of the year and restarts at R12C30 at the beginning first saturday of the year.

I guess my fellow SO members will point me towards loops, hence I need some guidance to start as I'm a VBA beginner.

Below is the code that I have written for my macro:

```
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R12C68"
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R54C68"
    Range("D4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R51C68"
    Range("D5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R45C68"
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R24C68"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R39C68"
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R66C68"
    Range("D9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R69C68"
    Range("D10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R27C68"
    Range("D11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R48C68"
    Range("D13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R33C68"
    Range("D14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='C:\Users\John\Downloads\[2022 OPS Performance Weekly Update - WE 100122.xlsx]Summary'!R30C68"
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Look up how to use variables ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables, https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html .. that sort of thing.

Comment: If you want to make it dynamic, you need to understand that every year will've different number of Saturdays. For ex `2022` has `53` Saturdays. `2023` will've `52` Saturdays & so on. `LOGIC`: **1.** Identify the year. **2.** Identify the first saturday in that year. **3.** Identify the last saturday in that year. **4.** Once you have the first and last saturday, the loop will be easy to make. You can use that loop to dynamically create the file name and identify the input cell from the dynamic file.
Give it a try and if you get stuck, post the code here and we will take it form there.

Answer (score 0):

try targeting the folder where you store your data.
Just extract the data once it is completed and delete it after.
create a helper sheet where the temporary data will be stored and another sheet where all the data will be compiled.

For this sample, the file name that I used is "**ThisFileExtractorName.xlsb**"

All .xlsx files from **"C:\Users\John\Downloads"** that
starts with "**2022**" will be extracted.

```
Sub CheckFolder()
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim fsoz As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

sFilePath = "C:\Users\John\Downloads\"
sFileName = Dir(sFilePath & "2022" & "*.xlsx")
Application.ScreenUpdating =  False
Do While Len(sFileName) >0
  If Right(sFilename, 4) = "xlsx" Then
     fsoz = fso.GetFileName(sFileName)
     Workbooks.Open sFilePath & sFileName
     Workbooks(fsoz).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B4").Copy _ 'just change the range based on available data. you can also make this dynamic.
                Workbooks("ThisFileExtractorName.xlsb").Worksheets("SheetDump").Range("A1")
     Workbooks(fsoz).Close SaveChanges:=True
     CopyDataStarts
  End If
  sFileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

then another sub for copy.

*Sheet1* is named *RAW* and *Sheet2* is named *SheetDump*

```
Sub CopyDataStarts()
  Dim s1 As long
  Dim s2 As long

 s1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row +1
 s2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
 Worksheets("SheetDump").Range("A2:B" & s2).Copy  Worksheets("RAW").Range("A" & s1)
 Sheet2.Range("A2:B" & s2).ClearContents  'clearing this part so we can use for the next loop
End Sub
```

Since you are able to compile all data into 1 Sheet "RAW" you can now use that sheet as a reference for your KPI.